# Books with images after removing the images

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, image, books

I know that drawn pictures are not permissible in islam but i read a book which has pictures so i erase those pictures and then read the book. Is it wrong for me to do so? It should be noted that i read history books and i read them mainly because i find them very interesting, informative as well as fun to read. Additionally i also intend to study history in university. Secondly, is it permissible to read books which have a picture only on their cover so i just remove that picture and then i read the book. Lastly, i read both of these types of books by downloading them free from the internet but that is obviously wrong but this is a different case because if i actually purchase these books wouldn't i be encouraging the use of pictures. On the other hand if i download them for free i am not promoting the use of images.

Answer (score 1):

You need a clarification...

**Drawing** pictures is prohibited not **looking at** drawn pictures. These are two different cases.

That's absolutely if these drawn pictures are not containing something already prohibited like women ; or else looking at it would be prohibited.

Comment: Ok thanks thats what i wanted to know, but now the question arises that is it permissible to give money and buy these books because then i would be promoting the use of images right so should i just download them free from the internet?

Comment: But wait, if drawing pictures is haram than so is looking at these drawn pictures right?